# Couchbase-lite replication error

Tags: couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

working with pure java and couchbase-lite.
running following code:

Manager manager = new Manager(new JavaContext("data"), Manager.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
Manager.enableLogging("Sync", Log.VERBOSE);

```
    final Database db = manager.getDatabase("sync_gateway");
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4984/sync_gateway/");
    Replication push = db.createPushReplication(url);
    Replication pull = db.createPullReplication(url);
    pull.setContinuous(true);
    push.setContinuous(true);
    com.couchbase.lite.auth.Authenticator auth = AuthenticatorFactory.createBasicAuthenticator("GUEST", "");
    push.setAuthenticator(auth);
    push.setAuthenticator(auth);
    pull.setAuthenticator(auth);
    push.start();
    pull.start();

    on line push.start()
    it through exception:
    Jun 11, 2015 8:46:23 PM com.couchbase.lite.util.SystemLogger e
    SEVERE: Sync: RemoteRequest.run() exception: %s
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at com.couchbase.lite.support.RemoteRequest.preemptivelySetAuthCredentials(RemoteRequest.java:281)
        at com.couchbase.lite.support.RemoteRequest.run(RemoteRequest.java:96)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Jun 11, 2015 8:48:02 PM com.couchbase.lite.util.SystemLogger e
    SEVERE: Sync: RemoteRequest.run() exception: %s
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
        at com.couchbase.lite.support.RemoteRequest.preemptivelySetAuthCredentials(RemoteRequest.java:281)
        at com.couchbase.lite.support.RemoteRequest.run(RemoteRequest.java:96)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

    Jun 11, 2015 8:48:11 PM com.couchbase.lite.util.SystemLogger e
    SEVERE: Sync: RemoteRequest.run() exception: %s
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at com.couchbase.lite.support.RemoteRequest.preemptivelySetAuthCredentials(RemoteRequest.java:281)
        at com.couchbase.lite.support.RemoteRequest.run(RemoteRequest.java:96)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang
```

.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I started my sync_gateway, and I want to sync my couchbase lite to couchbase full node.
I started sync_gateway with ip of couchbase full node. now as I know, I only need to run this couchbase lite replication code and my data of couchbase lite will be copied to couchbase full node.
kindly help.

Comment: See the discussion here -> https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-lite-replication-error/4096

Answer (score 0):

Referencing the discussion over at [Couchbase Forums](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/couchbase-lite-replication-error/4096) for the solution of this question.

Comment: could you re-paste the resolution here for posterity?

Comment: Short version of resolution: @Neeshan Niazi was using "GUEST" login with "" password. That causes an error, which is a since resolved bug https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-java-core/issues/661. For GUEST login, you don't need to use Authentication, so remove the _Authenticator auth =_ and _.setAuthenticator_ lines. Anonymous access (GUEST) is off by default. To enable, see http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/current/develop/guides/sync-gateway/authorizing-users/index.html#anonymous-access